# GIT Cherry-picking one commit X times

Tags: git, git-svn, cherry-pick, git-cherry-pick

I'm facing a strange behaviour with some commits on my SVN migrated GIT repository: 
I tried to cherry-pick onto a release branch a commit from the master that had been previously already merged onto the release branch with SVN. 
GIT did not detect it and added the code a second time in the source file modified. 
I was then able to cherry-pick it again and again and again and each time GIT added the commit code again !

In SVN, the merge property of the revision from master to the release branch is well saved.

This behaviour happens on only a few commit upon our 22K commits

Is there a direction onto which I should investigate to determine where this problem comes from ?

Comment: I'm confused by your question, because a cherry-pick is *not* a merge and does *not* get recorded as such. Therefore a cherry-pick cannot be expected to behave like a merge either. If you want a merge in Git, you must perform a *merge*, not a cherry-pick.

Comment: @Torek : We're using cherry-pick from master to release because we do want to pick only some fixes on a patch release. I should not have talked about merge (this is an old SVN user habits). What you say is because git does not record a cherry-pick has been done, it is normal in GIT that we can cherry-pick the same commit a multiple of times ?

Comment: Yes, though it depends on the commit.  As long as the context is OK, the cherry you're picking can be added repeatedly.  This is important, too, because the way you un-revert a revert is to either re-pick the original commit, or revert the revert (which is just inverse-applying a cherry).

Comment: @Torek : then why only a few commits have this behavior. For all others GIT detect that the code is already there and just do nothing.

Comment: Because, as I noted, it depends on the commit—more specifically, on the *context*. Remember that a patch has the form: "Look for these lines of code near this area. When you find them, remove specific lines and add these new lines." Suppose (simplified) you're looking for "Hello" surrounded by "A" above and "B" below, and the change is to *delete* "Hello". Suppose there are two occurrences of this in a file. You can apply the patch once, removing the one nearest the original line numbers, then you can apply it once more, removing the *second* "Hello", and now you can no longer apply it!

Comment: Or, suppose you have a patch that says "find A above and B below and insert a second line reading A after the first A and before the line reading B." You can apply this one as many times as you like, because the "after" version of the file is now "A" "A" "B", which has the required "A"-above-"B"-below. Apply again, you get "A" "A" "A" "B", and so on.

Comment: Most patches, however, effectively destroy the required pattern: you must have A above, X in the middle, and B below, and the change says "replace X with Y". Now you no longer have A, X, B: now you have A, Y, B. This was the case with our "Hello" example above: it has a limited count of applicability, and usually the limit is 1, rather than 2.

Comment: @torek : I tried to reproduced the case you described ("find A above and B below and insert a second line reading A after the first A and before the line reading B."). On the 2nd cherry-pick GIT would tell me "Nothing to commit". Depending of the scenarios (trying to cherry-pick several times different commit with same content) he would raise a conflict. But I wasn't able to reproduce with a simple case the behaviour where we end up with several times the same code.
Anyway, thank you for all your explanations

Comment: They're not the easiest thing to reproduce: my example was simplified. You need enough context (I think it's 3 lines in each direction) to "fool" Git.